# Query params with multiple slashes in URL

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

It goes like this...

**BASE**

Angular 4.2.1
Angular CLI 1.0.3

**QUESTION**

I have defined a URL route as `path: 'shop/:shopId',`

I have one `shop component`. In the shop component I am reading the shopId and passing it to the API. Everything is fine.

**BUT**

The URLs for shop can be smething like following sometimes

1. /shop/women
2. /shop/women/shirts
3. /shop/men/titan/watches

In the case of `#2` and `#3` I am not able to get `women/shirts` and `men/titan/watches` as shopId.

> Note : I don't have any limits on the URL, 
>        it can go upto 10 to 15 number of params so defining 10 to 15 routes would be messy.

It goes to another URL with 2, 3 or 4 slaces.

My question is, is it possible to get everything after `shop/` as `shopId`.

If yes, How ?

If no, what could be the solution, should I create separate routes for 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 number of params ?

Comment: If you want to handle URLs with multiple such segments, then you should set up routes accordingly ... I assume you do not actually have a category that is named `titan/watches`, but that those are two different categories, main and sub category, to begin with - so you should set your system up to receive those as two separate values as well; mashing them together into one make little sense.

Comment: I think you should define as many path as needed but all pointing at the same component.

Comment: @Ploppy currently I am doing that only, I was making sure if what I was thinking is possible or not. Thanks though

Comment: @CBroe Yes those 2 will be 2 different categories but I am passing canonical URLs in the API, so I was making sure if something like above question is possible or not

Comment: @CBroe I forgot to mention I don't have any limits on the URL there can be 10 or 15 number of params.

Comment: @Ploppy I forgot to mention I don't have any limits on the URL there can be 10 or 15 number of params.

Comment: Then, is the url really relevant? If it's not I would use a service to share the array of strings to the component.

Comment: Yes URL is relevant because 1. I need to pass it to api like this `?link=red/bags/dresses/eyewear/shirts/shoes/t-shirt/watches`, 2. We're re-architecting our website so these url's are already indexed by google, if we create the same URLs then it would be helpful for SEO also. Previous version was in php, new version is SPA in ng2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your route

```
{
    path: 'shop',
    component: ShopParentComponent,
    children : [{
        path: '**',
        component: ShopComponent
    }]
}
```

I have defined `shop` as parent route and defined a `**` child route to it. Child are using `ShopComponent` as component and Parent is using `ShopParentComponent`.

IN your `ShopComponent` constructor I am detecting changes in url using

```
_router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    console.log(val);
    if(val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        var url = this._router.url;
        //do anything with url
    }
});
```

imported routes like this

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
```

This will get you the current route

For example in case of this route

```
http://localhost/shop/a/b/c/d
```

it will give you

```
/shop/a/b/c/d
```

You can easily manipulate this url for your use.

Wondering what does your parent component holds, just one

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```